# Zero iteration count in PL SQL Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, oraclereports

I'm writing a query that should execute different select statements based on an IF statement. Haven't done any IFs in Oracle before and I'm not sure what's wrong, but I'm getting the error, zero iteration count and it points to the first line of code. I included the code and it's a lot, but you really only need to pay attention to the IFs.

```
IF :p_sales_type = 'all_cancel' THEN



  SELECT 
   TO_DATE(SUBSTR(Transaction_Date,1,10), 'MM/DD/YYYY'),Item_Number, 
    REGEXP_REPLACE(SUBSTR(Item_Or_Adj_Description,1,50),'([^[:print:]])',' ') AS Item_Or_Adj_Desctription, 
    Customer_Type, Document_ID, Dealer_ID, Sales_Type, Item_Quantity, Total_Fee, State_Fee, Transaction_Fee, AO_Fee, WDFW_Fee 
  FROM 
  ( 
    -- Sales Transactions 
   SELECT /*+ index(IT ITEM_X4) */ 
      TO_CHAR(IT.it_status_set_date - 2/24, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AS Transaction_Date,  -- Pacific Time
      TO_NUMBER(IT.ic_rcn) AS Item_Number, IT.it_descr AS Item_Or_Adj_Description, 
      DT.di_name AS Customer_Type, IT.it_docid AS Document_ID, IT.ag_id AS Dealer_ID, 
      CASE WHEN UPPER(IST.is_name) = 'ACTIVE' THEN 'SALE' ELSE IST.is_name END AS Sales_Type, 
      NVL(IT.it_quantity * CASE WHEN IT.is_id = 'AC' THEN 1 WHEN IT.is_id = 'DU' THEN 1 ELSE -1 END, 0) AS Item_Quantity,  -- Dups = 1
      NVL(IT.it_state_fee * CASE WHEN IT.is_id IN ('DC','SC') THEN -1.00 ELSE 1.00 END, 0.00) + 
    NVL(IT.it_other_fee * CASE WHEN IT.is_id IN ('DC','SC') THEN -1.00 ELSE 1.00 END, 0.00) AS Total_Fee, 
      NVL(IT.it_state_fee * CASE WHEN IT.is_id IN ('DC','SC') THEN -1.00 ELSE 1.00 END, 0.00) AS State_Fee, 
      NVL(IT.it_other_fee * CASE WHEN IT.is_id IN ('DC','SC') THEN -1.00 ELSE 1.00 END, 0.00) AS Transaction_Fee, 
      CASE WHEN IT.it_other_fee IS NULL OR IT.it_other_fee = 0.00 THEN 0.00 
        ELSE ROUND(IT.it_state_fee * CASE WHEN IT.is_id IN ('DC','SC') THEN -1.00 ELSE 1.00 END * (:p_ao_trx_fee / 100), 2) 
      END AS AO_Fee, 
      CASE WHEN IT.it_other_fee IS NULL OR IT.it_other_fee = 0.00 THEN 0.00 
        ELSE (IT.it_other_fee * CASE WHEN IT.is_id IN ('DC','SC') THEN -1.00 ELSE 1.00 END) - 
          ROUND((IT.it_state_fee * CASE WHEN IT.is_id IN ('DC','SC') THEN -1.00 ELSE 1.00 END * (:p_ao_trx_fee / 100)), 2) 
      END AS WDFW_Fee 
   FROM ITEM IT 
   JOIN DISCOUNT_TYPE DT ON DT.di_id = IT.di_id 
   JOIN ITEM_STATUS_TYPE IST ON IST.is_id = IT.is_id 
   WHERE IT.it_status_ind = 'A' -- Include active ITEM rows only. 
   AND (IT.is_id IN ('AC','DC','SC') OR (IT.is_id = 'DU' AND NVL(IT.it_state_fee, 0) != 0)) -- Exclude voids, exchanges, and false duplicates.
   AND IT.ic_rcn != '999' -- Exclude Dealer Fees. 
   AND IT.it_status_set_date BETWEEN :P_beg_dt  -- Pacific Time
                 AND :P_end_dt
    AND (:p_discount_type IS NULL OR DT.di_id = :p_discount_type)
  -- AND IST.is_name = :SalesType
   UNION ALL

   -- Item Adjustments
   SELECT 
      TO_CHAR(AJ.aj_adjustment_date - 2/24, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AS Transaction_Date,  -- Pacific Time
      TO_NUMBER(IT.ic_rcn) AS Item_Number, AJ.aj_comment AS Item_Or_Adj_Description, 
      DT.di_name AS Customer_Type, IT.it_docid AS Document_ID, AJ.ag_id AS Dealer_ID, 
      AJ.ajt_adjustment_type_name AS Sales_Type, 
      0 AS Item_Quantity, 
      NVL(AJ.aj_state_adj_amt, 0.00) + NVL(AJ.aj_other_adj_amt, 0.00) AS Total_Fee, 
      NVL(AJ.aj_state_adj_amt, 0.00) AS State_Fee, 
      NVL(AJ.aj_other_adj_amt, 0.00) AS Transaction_Fee, 
      CASE WHEN AJ.aj_other_adj_amt IS NULL OR AJ.aj_other_adj_amt = 0.00 THEN 0.00 
    ELSE ROUND(NVL(AJ.aj_state_adj_amt, 0.00) * (:p_ao_trx_fee / 100), 2) END AS AO_Fee, 
      CASE WHEN AJ.aj_other_adj_amt IS NULL OR AJ.aj_other_adj_amt = 0.00 THEN 0.00 
    ELSE AJ.aj_other_adj_amt - ROUND(NVL(AJ.aj_state_adj_amt, 0.00) * (:p_ao_trx_fee / 100), 2) END AS WDFW_Fee 
   FROM ADJUSTMENT AJ 
   JOIN ITEM IT ON IT.it_id = AJ.it_id 
   JOIN DISCOUNT_TYPE DT ON DT.di_id = IT.di_id 
   WHERE AJ.aj_status_ind = 'A' -- Include active adjustments only. 
   AND AJ.it_id IS NOT NULL -- Include Item Adjustments only; rows with a foreign key to the ITEM table are Item Adjustments. 
   AND AJ.ajt_id != '0' -- Unreturned Doc Charge is not an Item Adjustment, it's a Lump Sum Adjustment to the Dealers account. 
   AND IT.ic_rcn != '999' -- Exclude Dealer Fees. 
   AND AJ.aj_adjustment_date BETWEEN :P_beg_dt  -- Pacific Time
                 AND :P_end_dt
    AND (:p_discount_type IS NULL OR DT.di_id = :p_discount_type)
   --AND AJ.Ajt_Adjustment_Type_Name = :SalesType
  ) ReportDetails 

  WHERE-- Sales_Type = :SalesType
                 (:p_ic_rcn is null OR :p_ic_rcn = Item_Number)
                 AND (:p_dealer_id IS NULL OR Dealer_ID = :p_dealer_id)
                 AND Sales_Type in ('DEALER CANCEL', 'STATE CANCEL')



  ORDER BY TO_DATE(SUBSTR(Transaction_Date,1,10), 'MM/DD/YYYY'), Item_Number,  -- Transaction Date, RCN (numerical order), order RCN was purchased. 
       TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(Transaction_Date, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 'SSSSS');


  ELSE IF :p_sales_type = 'item_adjustment' THEN


   -- Item Adjustments
   SELECT 
      TO_CHAR(AJ.aj_adjustment_date - 2/24, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AS Transaction_Date,  -- Pacific Time
      TO_NUMBER(IT.ic_rcn) AS Item_Number, AJ.aj_comment AS Item_Or_Adj_Description, 
      DT.di_name AS Customer_Type, IT.it_docid AS Document_ID, AJ.ag_id AS Dealer_ID, 
      AJ.ajt_adjustment_type_name AS Sales_Type, 
      0 AS Item_Quantity, 
      NVL(AJ.aj_state_adj_amt, 0.00) + NVL(AJ.aj_other_adj_amt, 0.00) AS Total_Fee, 
      NVL(AJ.aj_state_adj_amt, 0.00) AS State_Fee, 
      NVL(AJ.aj_other_adj_amt, 0.00) AS Transaction_Fee, 
      CASE WHEN AJ.aj_other_adj_amt IS NULL OR AJ.aj_other_adj_amt = 0.00 THEN 0.00 
    ELSE ROUND(NVL(AJ.aj_state_adj_amt, 0.00) * (:p_ao_trx_fee / 100), 2) END AS AO_Fee, 
      CASE WHEN AJ.aj_other_adj_amt IS NULL OR AJ.aj_other_adj_amt = 0.00 THEN 0.00 
    ELSE AJ.aj_other_adj_amt - ROUND(NVL(AJ.aj_state_adj_amt, 0.00) * (:p_ao_trx_fee / 100), 2) END AS WDFW_Fee 
   FROM ADJUSTMENT AJ 
   JOIN ITEM IT ON IT.it_id = AJ.it_id 
   JOIN DISCOUNT_TYPE DT ON DT.di_id = IT.di_id 
   WHERE AJ.aj_status_ind = 'A' -- Include active adjustments only. 
   AND AJ.it_id IS NOT NULL -- Include Item Adjustments only; rows with a foreign key to the ITEM table are Item Adjustments. 
   AND AJ.ajt_id != '0' -- Unreturned Doc Charge is not an Item Adjustment, it's a Lump Sum Adjustment to the Dealers account. 
   AND IT.ic_rcn != '999' -- Exclude Dealer Fees. 
   AND AJ.aj_adjustment_date BETWEEN :P_beg_dt  -- Pacific Time
                 AND :P_end_dt
    AND (:p_discount_type IS NULL OR DT.di_id = :p_discount_type)
    WHERE-- Sales_Type = :SalesType
                 (:p_ic_rcn is null OR :p_ic_rcn = Item_Number)
                 AND (:p_dealer_id IS NULL OR Dealer_ID = :p_dealer_id)
                 AND Sales_Type = 'ADJUSTMENT'

    ORDER BY TO_DATE(SUBSTR(Transaction_Date,1,10), 'MM/DD/YYYY'), Item_Number,  -- Transaction Date, RCN (numerical order), order RCN was purchased. 
       TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(Transaction_Date, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 'SSSSS');

  ELSE IF :p_sales_type IS NULL 


  SELECT 
   TO_DATE(SUBSTR(Transaction_Date,1,10), 'MM/DD/YYYY'),Item_Number, 
    REGEXP_REPLACE(SUBSTR(Item_Or_Adj_Description,1,50),'([^[:print:]])',' ') AS Item_Or_Adj_Desctription, 
    Customer_Type, Document_ID, Dealer_ID, Sales_Type, Item_Quantity, Total_Fee, State_Fee, Transaction_Fee, AO_Fee, WDFW_Fee 
  FROM 
  ( 
    -- Sales Transactions 
   SELECT /*+ index(IT ITEM_X4) */ 
      TO_CHAR(IT.it_status_set_date - 2/24, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AS Transaction_Date,  -- Pacific Time
      TO_NUMBER(IT.ic_rcn) AS Item_Number, IT.it_descr AS Item_Or_Adj_Description, 
      DT.di_name AS Customer_Type, IT.it_docid AS Document_ID, IT.ag_id AS Dealer_ID, 
      CASE WHEN UPPER(IST.is_name) = 'ACTIVE' THEN 'SALE' ELSE IST.is_name END AS Sales_Type, 
      NVL(IT.it_quantity * CASE WHEN IT.is_id = 'AC' THEN 1 WHEN IT.is_id = 'DU' THEN 1 ELSE -1 END, 0) AS Item_Quantity,  -- Dups = 1
      NVL(IT.it_state_fee * CASE WHEN IT.is_id IN ('DC','SC') THEN -1.00 ELSE 1.00 END, 0.00) + 
    NVL(IT.it_other_fee * CASE WHEN IT.is_id IN ('DC','SC') THEN -1.00 ELSE 1.00 END, 0.00) AS Total_Fee, 
      NVL(IT.it_state_fee * CASE WHEN IT.is_id IN ('DC','SC') THEN -1.00 ELSE 1.00 END, 0.00) AS State_Fee, 
      NVL(IT.it_other_fee * CASE WHEN IT.is_id IN ('DC','SC') THEN -1.00 ELSE 1.00 END, 0.00) AS Transaction_Fee, 
      CASE WHEN IT.it_other_fee IS NULL OR IT.it_other_fee = 0.00 THEN 0.00 
        ELSE ROUND(IT.it_state_fee * CASE WHEN IT.is_id IN ('DC','SC') THEN -1.00 ELSE 1.00 END * (:p_ao_trx_fee / 100), 2) 
      END AS AO_Fee, 
      CASE WHEN IT.it_other_fee IS NULL OR IT.it_other_fee = 0.00 THEN 0.00 
        ELSE (IT.it_other_fee * CASE WHEN IT.is_id IN ('DC','SC') THEN -1.00 ELSE 1.00 END) - 
          ROUND((IT.it_state_fee * CASE WHEN IT.is_id IN ('DC','SC') THEN -1.00 ELSE 1.00 END * (:p_ao_trx_fee / 100)), 2) 
      END AS WDFW_Fee 
   FROM ITEM IT 
   JOIN DISCOUNT_TYPE DT ON DT.di_id = IT.di_id 
   JOIN ITEM_STATUS_TYPE IST ON IST.is_id = IT.is_id 
   WHERE IT.it_status_ind = 'A' -- Include active ITEM rows only. 
   AND (IT.is_id IN ('AC','DC','SC') OR (IT.is_id = 'DU' AND NVL(IT.it_state_fee, 0) != 0)) -- Exclude voids, exchanges, and false duplicates.
   AND IT.ic_rcn != '999' -- Exclude Dealer Fees. 
   AND IT.it_status_set_date BETWEEN :P_beg_dt  -- Pacific Time
                 AND :P_end_dt
    AND (:p_discount_type IS NULL OR DT.di_id = :p_discount_type)
  -- AND IST.is_name = :SalesType
   UNION ALL

   -- Item Adjustments
   SELECT 
      TO_CHAR(AJ.aj_adjustment_date - 2/24, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AS Transaction_Date,  -- Pacific Time
      TO_NUMBER(IT.ic_rcn) AS Item_Number, AJ.aj_comment AS Item_Or_Adj_Description, 
      DT.di_name AS Customer_Type, IT.it_docid AS Document_ID, AJ.ag_id AS Dealer_ID, 
      AJ.ajt_adjustment_type_name AS Sales_Type, 
      0 AS Item_Quantity, 
      NVL(AJ.aj_state_adj_amt, 0.00) + NVL(AJ.aj_other_adj_amt, 0.00) AS Total_Fee, 
      NVL(AJ.aj_state_adj_amt, 0.00) AS State_Fee, 
      NVL(AJ.aj_other_adj_amt, 0.00) AS Transaction_Fee, 
      CASE WHEN AJ.aj_other_adj_amt IS NULL OR AJ.aj_other_adj_amt = 0.00 THEN 0.00 
    ELSE ROUND(NVL(AJ.aj_state_adj_amt, 0.00) * (:p_ao_trx_fee / 100), 2) END AS AO_Fee, 
      CASE WHEN AJ.aj_other_adj_amt IS NULL OR AJ.aj_other_adj_amt = 0.00 THEN 0.00 
    ELSE AJ.aj_other_adj_amt - ROUND(NVL(AJ.aj_state_adj_amt, 0.00) * (:p_ao_trx_fee / 100), 2) END AS WDFW_Fee 
   FROM ADJUSTMENT AJ 
   JOIN ITEM IT ON IT.it_id = AJ.it_id 
   JOIN DISCOUNT_TYPE DT ON DT.di_id = IT.di_id 
   WHERE AJ.aj_status_ind = 'A' -- Include active adjustments only. 
   AND AJ.it_id IS NOT NULL -- Include Item Adjustments only; rows with a foreign key to the ITEM table are Item Adjustments. 
   AND AJ.ajt_id != '0' -- Unreturned Doc Charge is not an Item Adjustment, it's a Lump Sum Adjustment to the Dealers account. 
   AND IT.ic_rcn != '999' -- Exclude Dealer Fees. 
   AND AJ.aj_adjustment_date BETWEEN :P_beg_dt  -- Pacific Time
                 AND :P_end_dt
    AND (:p_discount_type IS NULL OR DT.di_id = :p_discount_type)
   --AND AJ.Ajt_Adjustment_Type_Name = :SalesType
  ) ReportDetails 

  WHERE         (:p_ic_rcn is null OR :p_ic_rcn = Item_Number)
                 AND (:p_dealer_id IS NULL OR Dealer_ID = :p_dealer_id)



  ORDER BY TO_DATE(SUBSTR(Transaction_Date,1,10), 'MM/DD/YYYY'), Item_Number,  -- Transaction Date, RCN (numerical order), order RCN was purchased. 
       TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(Transaction_Date, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 'SSSSS');


ELSE

  SELECT 
   TO_DATE(SUBSTR(Transaction_Date,1,10), 'MM/DD/YYYY'),Item_Number, 
    REGEXP_REPLACE(SUBSTR(Item_Or_Adj_Description,1,50),'([^[:print:]])',' ') AS Item_Or_Adj_Desctription, 
    Customer_Type, Document_ID, Dealer_ID, Sales_Type, Item_Quantity, Total_Fee, State_Fee, Transaction_Fee, AO_Fee, WDFW_Fee 
  FROM 
  ( 
    -- Sales Transactions 
   SELECT /*+ index(IT ITEM_X4) */ 
      TO_CHAR(IT.it_status_set_date - 2/24, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AS Transaction_Date,  -- Pacific Time
      TO_NUMBER(IT.ic_rcn) AS Item_Number, IT.it_descr AS Item_Or_Adj_Description, 
      DT.di_name AS Customer_Type, IT.it_docid AS Document_ID, IT.ag_id AS Dealer_ID, 
      CASE WHEN UPPER(IST.is_name) = 'ACTIVE' THEN 'SALE' ELSE IST.is_name END AS Sales_Type, 
      NVL(IT.it_quantity * CASE WHEN IT.is_id = 'AC' THEN 1 WHEN IT.is_id = 'DU' THEN 1 ELSE -1 END, 0) AS Item_Quantity,  -- Dups = 1
      NVL(IT.it_state_fee * CASE WHEN IT.is_id IN ('DC','SC') THEN -1.00 ELSE 1.00 END, 0.00) + 
    NVL(IT.it_other_fee * CASE WHEN IT.is_id IN ('DC','SC') THEN -1.00 ELSE 1.00 END, 0.00) AS Total_Fee, 
      NVL(IT.it_state_fee * CASE WHEN IT.is_id IN ('DC','SC') THEN -1.00 ELSE 1.00 END, 0.00) AS State_Fee, 
      NVL(IT.it_other_fee * CASE WHEN IT.is_id IN ('DC','SC') THEN -1.00 ELSE 1.00 END, 0.00) AS Transaction_Fee, 
      CASE WHEN IT.it_other_fee IS NULL OR IT.it_other_fee = 0.00 THEN 0.00 
        ELSE ROUND(IT.it_state_fee * CASE WHEN IT.is_id IN ('DC','SC') THEN -1.00 ELSE 1.00 END * (:p_ao_trx_fee / 100), 2) 
      END AS AO_Fee, 
      CASE WHEN IT.it_other_fee IS NULL OR IT.it_other_fee = 0.00 THEN 0.00 
        ELSE (IT.it_other_fee * CASE WHEN IT.is_id IN ('DC','SC') THEN -1.00 ELSE 1.00 END) - 
          ROUND((IT.it_state_fee * CASE WHEN IT.is_id IN ('DC','SC') THEN -1.00 ELSE 1.00 END * (:p_ao_trx_fee / 100)), 2) 
      END AS WDFW_Fee 
   FROM ITEM IT 
   JOIN DISCOUNT_TYPE DT ON DT.di_id = IT.di_id 
   JOIN ITEM_STATUS_TYPE IST ON IST.is_id = IT.is_id 
   WHERE IT.it_status_ind = 'A' -- Include active ITEM rows only. 
   AND (IT.is_id IN ('AC','DC','SC') OR (IT.is_id = 'DU' AND NVL(IT.it_state_fee, 0) != 0)) -- Exclude voids, exchanges, and false duplicates.
   AND IT.ic_rcn != '999' -- Exclude Dealer Fees. 
   AND IT.it_status_set_date BETWEEN :P_beg_dt  -- Pacific Time
                 AND :P_end_dt
    AND (:p_discount_type IS NULL OR DT.di_id = :p_discount_type)
  -- AND IST.is_name = :SalesType
   UNION ALL

   -- Item Adjustments
   SELECT 
      TO_CHAR(AJ.aj_adjustment_date - 2/24, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AS Transaction_Date,  -- Pacific Time
      TO_NUMBER(IT.ic_rcn) AS Item_Number, AJ.aj_comment AS Item_Or_Adj_Description, 
      DT.di_name AS Customer_Type, IT.it_docid AS Document_ID, AJ.ag_id AS Dealer_ID, 
      AJ.ajt_adjustment_type_name AS Sales_Type, 
      0 AS Item_Quantity, 
      NVL(AJ.aj_state_adj_amt, 0.00) + NVL(AJ.aj_other_adj_amt, 0.00) AS Total_Fee, 
      NVL(AJ.aj_state_adj_amt, 0.00) AS State_Fee, 
      NVL(AJ.aj_other_adj_amt, 0.00) AS Transaction_Fee, 
      CASE WHEN AJ.aj_other_adj_amt IS NULL OR AJ.aj_other_adj_amt = 0.00 THEN 0.00 
    ELSE ROUND(NVL(AJ.aj_state_adj_amt, 0.00) * (:p_ao_trx_fee / 100), 2) END AS AO_Fee, 
      CASE WHEN AJ.aj_other_adj_amt IS NULL OR AJ.aj_other_adj_amt = 0.00 THEN 0.00 
    ELSE AJ.aj_other_adj_amt - ROUND(NVL(AJ.aj_state_adj_amt, 0.00) * (:p_ao_trx_fee / 100), 2) END AS WDFW_Fee 
   FROM ADJUSTMENT AJ 
   JOIN ITEM IT ON IT.it_id = AJ.it_id 
   JOIN DISCOUNT_TYPE DT ON DT.di_id = IT.di_id 
   WHERE AJ.aj_status_ind = 'A' -- Include active adjustments only. 
   AND AJ.it_id IS NOT NULL -- Include Item Adjustments only; rows with a foreign key to the ITEM table are Item Adjustments. 
   AND AJ.ajt_id != '0' -- Unreturned Doc Charge is not an Item Adjustment, it's a Lump Sum Adjustment to the Dealers account. 
   AND IT.ic_rcn != '999' -- Exclude Dealer Fees. 
   AND AJ.aj_adjustment_date BETWEEN :P_beg_dt  -- Pacific Time
                 AND :P_end_dt
    AND (:p_discount_type IS NULL OR DT.di_id = :p_discount_type)
   --AND AJ.Ajt_Adjustment_Type_Name = :SalesType
  ) ReportDetails 

  WHERE        Sales_Type = :p_sales_type
                AND (:p_ic_rcn is null OR :p_ic_rcn = Item_Number)
                 AND (:p_dealer_id IS NULL OR Dealer_ID = :p_dealer_id)




  ORDER BY TO_DATE(SUBSTR(Transaction_Date,1,10), 'MM/DD/YYYY'), Item_Number,  -- Transaction Date, RCN (numerical order), order RCN was purchased. 
       TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(Transaction_Date, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 'SSSSS');

  END IF;
```

Comment: What is the actual error code and statement? In a PL/SQL context SQL statements such as these would need a `SELECT .. INTO ..` or some other way of handling the result set.

Comment: What ORA error number are you getting?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you were executing the individual statements and they all worked.  Then you added the IF's to choose the correct statement to execute and started getting errors.  Is that what occurred?

Comment: @BobJarvis Yes, that is correct.

Comment: OK, then @Ollie's answer about "you'll need an INTO clause" applies, assuming these statements only return a single row. If they can return multiple rows you'll need to treat them as cursors - I suggest looking at the PL/SQL reference manual at http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370.pdf, and in particular the sections about cursors and FOR loops.

Comment: @RageQwit The fact that this SQL is in an Oracle Report changes the question. You may not be able to use a PL/SQL condition like this in an Oracle Report query block other than native SQL. You might be able to use a beforeReport trigger, or a conditional layout that executes the desired SQL block. Another option would be in your Oracle Report SQL block you could join all three statements with a `UNION ALL` and then include mutually exclusive parameters in the `WHERE` clauses so only one statement returns values.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what you mean by "zero iteration count" but you need an `INTO` clause to select your results into and use `ELSIF` rather than `ELSE IF`:

```
IF :p_sales_type = 'all_cancel' 
THEN
   SELECT col_list
     INTO variable_list
     FROM tables
    WHERE <where_clause>;
ELSIF :p_sales_type = 'item_adjustment' 
THEN 
   SELECT col_list
     INTO variable_list
     FROM tables
    WHERE <where_clause>;
ELSIF :p_sales_type IS NULL  
THEN
   SELECT col_list
     INTO variable_list
     FROM tables
    WHERE <where_clause>;
ELSE
   SELECT col_list
     INTO variable_list
     FROM tables
    WHERE <where_clause>;
END IF;
```

You have a spurious colon in front of your `p_sales_type` variable/parameter.
Finally, it might be worth wrapping `p_sales_type` in an `UPPER` as in `UPPER(p_sales_type) = 'ALL_CANCEL'` to make sure you don't have any unintentional mismatches (unless, of course, you are sure of the case of the values).

Hope it helps...

Comment: The colon is because it is a parameter in an Oracle report, and it was working fine until I added the IFs @Ollie

Comment: Fair enough, then you'll need to keep the colon if it is an Oracle Reports variable.